# How can I create a new column with bout hour and minute together?

Tags: python

How can I create a new column with both hour and minute together? I can do them separately as shown below but is it possible to combine them in one column?

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range("2000-01-01", periods=10, freq="T"))
df.columns = ['index']

df['hour'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['index']).hour
df['minute'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['index']).minute
```

```
df['hour_minute'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['index']).hour.minute
```

Comment: use a `f` string? https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/formatted-string-literals-f-strings-python/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can concat them:

```
df['hour_minute'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['index']).hour.astype(str)+ ':'+ pd.DatetimeIndex(df['index']).minute.astype(str)
```

Its simple but will be `object` type tho. If you want datetime format you can either convert this newly added column as: (Thanks @Felix Tang)

```
df['hour_minute'] = pd.to_datetime(df['hour_minute'],format="%H:%M")
```

Or can directly convert original as:

```
df['hour_minute'] = pd.to_datetime(pd.DatetimeIndex(df['index']),format="%H:%M")
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm unable to edit Hamza's answer. Note that if you use .info on the dataframe you'll find that the new column is an object instead of datetime format.

Original answer:

```
df['hour_minute'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['index']).hour.astype(str)+ ':'+ pd.DatetimeIndex(df['index']).minute.astype(str)
```

I suggest you add the following to change the new column to type datetime.

```
df['hour_minute'] = pd.to_datetime(df['hour_minute'],format="%H:%M")
```

Comment: You can add it as comment/ submit edit request. Anyways thanks it is indeed the case. However OP only asked for combining them thats why I didnt add that but will add this in my answer